# Is it possible to store image embedings with a labels in csv file in android java

Tags: android, image, csv, face-recognition

I am working on face recognition in android. when I capture the image it will store in convert in Bitmap and how to store the image Bitmaps in csv file with a label.

Comment: `it will store in convert in Bitmap` ?? What is happening? What is 'in convert'?

Comment: Well, the question could be little bit improved. What you want to achieve and why? Seems like you are trying to do something with bitmaps which doesn't make sense.  If you are working with images you usually want to stay in binary format just for the performance. The labels can be in csv file, but the data of image you usually store somewhere else (don't know your infrastructure).  In case you really want to do it this way, you should look for bytes to string conversions.